# How a client side object (Proxy) register to an event to be fired on the server side?

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

I would like to make a class where the client side (proxy) of the instantiated object can register to an event (or delegate) and be informed whenever this event is fired on the server side.

I tried directly but I get a `SecurityException` informing me that `System.DelegateSerializationHolder` cannot be serialized at this security level.

Is there a way around this?

Example:

```
MyClass proxy = Activator.GetObject(typeof(MyClass ), uri) as MyClass;
proxy.OnMyEvent += new MyEventHandler(this.Callback);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Not directly anyway.

Your choices would be to either have the client call back to the server and register a with it a port for out of band controls from the server.  This could open up all sorts of security concerns.

Probably the best way would be to have the client poll the server to see if any events need to be processed.  This leaves the control of information requests in the clients domain, and is how Microsoft Exchange and other products I've worked with tend to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but it's deactivated by default.

The default .net Remoting deserialization level is `Low`, which does not allow Delegates to be passed over the Remoting boundary. You can create a custom BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider with a deserialization level of `Full` and pass this provider to your channel (on the server side).

Here's a VB.NET example; see [the MSDN article on *Automatic Deserialization in .NET Framework Remoting*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dxse167.aspx) for a C# example.

```
Dim myChannel = New TcpServerChannel("", myPort, _
                                     New BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider() With {.TypeFilterLevel = Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.TypeFilterLevel.Full})
```